# Showing that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^x}{x^n} = \infty$

Tags: limits

I have been told that I can show this by showing two things, first that
$$f(x) = \frac{e^x}{x^n}>\frac{e^n}{n^n}, \quad (x > n)$$
then
$$f'(x) = \frac{e^x(x-n)}{x^{n+1}}>\frac{e^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}, \quad (x > n+1)$$
I have managed to show both of these things, the first is fairly easy and the second follows
$$\frac{e^x(x-n)}{x^{n+1}} = \frac{e^x}{x^n} - \frac{n}{x}\frac{e^x}{x^{n}} > \frac{e^x}{x^n}\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg) > \frac{e^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}$$

but I do not see how this helps me deduce that

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^x}{x^n} = \infty$

Just to clarify, I know how to show this a few other ways, I am interested in showing this way!

Comment: Just use L'Hospital, repeatedly (n times)

Comment: I understand, but why go through the rigour of proving the previous parts if they are not needed?

Comment: What parts ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $n$ is **fixed**. So you've shown a lower bound that looks like

$$f'(x) > \frac{e^{n + 1}}{n^{n + 1}} = c > 0$$

once $x$ is large enough. An easy application of the mean value theorem shows that this will force $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$; geometrically, $f$ must sit above a line with slope $c$. (Note that you don't actually even need to know $f(x) > e^n/n^n$ here...).

Comment: from the mean value theorem I obtain $$f(x) = f'(\xi)(x-n-1) + f(n+1) > c(x-n-1) + f(n+1)$$ taking the limit of both sides as $x \rightarrow \infty$ we obtain the result?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

You can apply L'Hospital's Rule $n$ times to get:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{e^x}{x^n} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{e^x}{n!} = n!\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}e^x = \infty$

Comment: OP knows how to solve the problem using other means. He  just doesn't know how to make use of lower bound of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ to get to the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

$e^x =$

$1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + ...\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} .....$

Hence:

$e^x \gt \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ , for $x \gt 0$, $ n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \ge 1$.

$\frac{e^x}{x^n} \gt \frac{x}{(n+1)!}$.

Finally:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^x}{x^n} \ge \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{(n+1)!} = \infty$.